# What was Magnus' dream about?

Tags: shadowhunters

Magnus Bane has a dream about blood streams in a city and darkness on the rise. Chaos with no rules.

I think we first hear of it in the second book, where he mentions it. And in *Angels of Fire* he talks to Simon Lewis after they just send the summoned demon away. Simon says to Magnus he should at least remember his name, now that he is risking his life to summon an angel. Magnus on the other hand states that Simon isn't risking anything for him - he himself is only staying for Alec. And then he repeats the dream he had about the blood streams in a city and darkness approaching. He is ending his telling with the claim, that he would have left into hiding if it wasn't for his love to Alec.

So I am curious: what is his dream refering to? Is it the war in the last book, where elves kill so many Shadowhunters in Alicante? Or is it about the upcoming battle in the follow up series between the other elves who have invented anti-Shadowhunter runes with the help of the Warlock of LA? Or something totally different?

Answer (score 0):

Magnus is talking about what would've happened if Clary and the others had not stopped Jonathan (her brother Jonathan, not Jace) from carrying out his plans.

He had planned to rid the world of Shadowhunters before moving onto the Downworld, or as [the wiki](https://shadowhunters.fandom.com/wiki/Sebastian_Morgenstern) states, "Sebastian dropped his guise and joined the demons in their killing".

The blood from his victims would turn the streets red and the bones made into towers.